# How do I input variables into a Simulink model through MATLAB script (SimDriveline)

Tags: matlab, input, model, simulink

For my coursework project in MATLAB, I have decided to build a drive-line model within Simulink, using the SimDriveline toolbox. The idea is to get the user to input values for the various parameters that are associated with each part of the model, such as the engine or the transmission. I would like to able to write this in a MATLAB script, but I'm not sure how to assign the values that are input to the Simulink model. For instance, the stock `sdl_vehicle` example that comes with SimDriveline. I am aware of the `sim()` command, but I am still confused on how to use it properly.

Also at the end of the simulation, the program is supposed to display the graphs that are collected in the scope window. I know that in the window itself that the scope can be printed to a figure, but is it possible to print that scope to a figure through MATLAB script?

This is the first time I have ever used a program like MATLAB. I would appreciate any help I could get, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Having variables assigned in your base workspace, you can use these variables in block parameters. Just write X=1 in Matlab and try a constant block using the parameter X for a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simulink block called `simin`:
http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html?searchHighlight=simin

I used it some days back and it worked quite well. You can use the block in your model and define some signals/varibles as input.
After that you may write a Matlab-Script with an input function to set all the previous defined input values.